# Using iTextSharp to export to PDF and repeat headers

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5, itext

I have gone through quite a few posts and tried everything that were suggested, but the header is not being repeated on the page that my webgrid flows over to.

Here is my Code :

```
public FileStreamResult ExportCombinedPDF(int ProjectID)
    {
        List<PipelineDetails> PipeList = new List<PipelineDetails>();
        ProjectManager PM = new ProjectManager();

        PipeList = PM.GetPipelineList(ProjectID);

        //This is the css styling for the webgrid
        string webgridstyle = PM.Pipeline_HtmlForExport(ProjectID);
        //This is creating the table with other details also being exported
        string ProjectHtml = PM.Project_HtmlForExport(ProjectID);

        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: PipeList, canPage: false, canSort: false);
        string gridHtml = grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
                                       headerStyle: "webGridHeader",
                                       alternatingRowStyle: "webGridAlt",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                 grid.Column("NodeNumber", "Node Nr."),
                 grid.Column("Accumulated_Length", "Accumulated Length"),
                 grid.Column("Elevation", "Elevation"),
                 grid.Column("Pipe_Outside_Diameter", "Pipe Outside Diameter"),
                 grid.Column("Wall_Thickness", "Wall Thickness"),
                 grid.Column("Control_Point_Description", "Control Point Description"),
                 grid.Column("Control_Point_Size", "Control Point Size"))).ToString();

        string exportData = String.Format("<html><body>{0}{1} <br /> {2}</body></html>", "<style>" + webgridstyle + "</style>", ProjectHtml, gridHtml);

        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exportData);
        using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

            Font headerFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 10);
            Font rowfont = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 10);

            writer.CloseStream = false;
            document.Open();

            var xmlWorker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
            xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

            document.Close();
            output.Position = 0;

            return File(output, "application/pdf", "Pipeline_Report.pdf");

            //return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
        }

    }
```

I have tried adding `repeat-header:yes` to my css, but this did not work. I also tried adding the following to my code below, which also did not work :

```
//This was done before the document was opened :
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(7);

            table.HeaderRows = 2;

//This was done before the document was closed :

            document.Add(table);
```

But as mentioned, this also did not work. I cant imagine it is so difficult to set something to repeat a header.

Otherwise, the next option would be to just set the WebGrid to start on the new page. Is this even possible ?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get a pagebreak to work. So thought as this is also giving me a result that I wanted, I would post as an answer.

I changed my exportData string by adding a PageBreak :

```
string exportData = String.Format("<html><body>{0}{1} <p style='page-break-after:always;'></p> {2}</body></html>", "<style>" + webgridstyle + "</style>", ProjectHtml, gridHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had success with `repeat-header:yes` if you add that line within `.webgrid-table` in your webgridstyle string in this way

```
string webgridstyle = " .webgrid-table {    " +

                "           border: solid 0.1px #000000; " +
                "           background-color: white; " +
                "           repeat-header:yes;  " +
                "       }   " +
```

This is how it worked for me. As you can see from screenshot, 2nd page has my repeating header as well

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have not worked on this project in a while, but if I am able to find time, I will try your suggestion and get back to you. Thanks again!

Comment: So I needed to do the same sort of thing on another project and gave your suggestion a try, but it does not seem to work :(

Comment: your CSS resides in `PM.Pipeline_HtmlForExport()`? and do you have the line `repeat-header:yes;` anywhere in your css?

Comment: Correct yes. No where else no. :(

Comment: can you post your `webgridstyle` css

Comment: in the meantime I can direct you to one of my questions that has my full code that will achieve this functionality for you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47039128/7610106 
first section of code has the line `string webgridstyle = style.GetCss();` which calls the class with the css styling. And second second section of code has the styling class which has `repeat-header:yes;` which solved the problem for me. I hope that helps.