# PDF Itextsharp printing is adding margins on right and bottom of page on print output

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, itext

I have a PDF export function(ality) where I have the following output when the result is rendered on the page/view

[image: Output on Webpage]

As you can see, the contents of the table are center aligned on the page and all seems perfect. But upon printing the contents (table) are shrinked slightly and output is pushed slightly left and slightly up, meaning there's extra space on the right and bottom of the page.

[image: Output on printer]

This distorted output appears like this on both paper printer and document writer printing outputs. I cannot pinpoint whats causing this as all seems fine in the code. The same code is used to create and output a PDF file and all contents appeared centered perfectly. Printing from the webpage (first image) is where the issue is. Is this a CSS issue or is it an XMLworker issue?

My export method is as follows (irrelevant code trimmed out)

```
    public ActionResult ExportFileToPrint()
    { 
        var printList = conStrings.GetReport(search);     

        string webgridstyle = style.GetCss(); //Pdf css

        /*Grid with records data (rows)*/
        string gridHtml = style.GetGrid(printList);

        string exportData = String.Format
            ("<html>" +
            "<head>{0}</head>" +
            "<body>" +
            "<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>" +
            "{1}</body>" +
            "</html>",
            "<style>" + webgridstyle + "</style>", gridHtml);

        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exportData);
        using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            //Create a System.IO.FileStream object:
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
            //Create a iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter object, to write the Document to the Specified FileStream:
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

            writer.CloseStream = false;

            //Page event handler to insert TIMESTAMP and PAGE X of Y
            writer.PageEvent = new PdfHeaderFooter();

            //Parse to PDF (open document for writing)
            document.Open();

            //document header Table that only appears on first page
            PdfPTable tables = style.GetHeaderTable();
            //tables.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER; //
            //CENTER CONTENTS HERE??
            tables.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            //tables.
            //Add table to document                                    
            document.Add(tables);

            var xmlWorker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
            xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

            //Close the Document - this saves the document contents to the output stream
            document.Close();
            output.Position = 0;

            //return file to browser page
            return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
        }
```

Part of the table CSS from this line `string webgridstyle = style.GetCss();`, to style contents. Centering table here with `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` does not seem to have fixed the issue.

```
public string GetCss()
    {
        string webgridstyle = " .webgrid-table {    " +
                "           font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;    " +
                "           font-size: 11px;    " +
                "           font-weight: normal;    " +
                "           width: 100%;    " +
                //"           display: table; " +
                "           border-collapse: collapse;  " +
                "           border-spacing: 0; " +
                "           border: solid 0.1px #000000; " +
                "           background-color: white;  repeat-header:yes;  margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" +
                "       }   " +
                "       " +
```

[PDF Files download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v68eibb1jrg3neh/pdf_files_so.7z?dl=0)

[image: Download/Print File]

Zip file - includes two files both from the same web page app
one is downloaded into a pdf which shows contents properly aligned
the other is printed with content not aligned properly

**UPDATE 1**

So I just tried a random link thats not my own, that has its own pdf and I am getting the same issue. So its most likely not an html/css/writer issue then as stated by Bruno.

Link [Stackoverflow - The Developer Ecosystem](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/hubfs/Q3%20Report%20-%20Education/The%20Developer%20Ecosystem-%20Education%20And%20The%20New%20Generation%20Of%20Coders.pdf)

View

[image: View of pdf]

Print

[image: Output of PDF]

**UPDATE 2**

Another thing that totally slipped my mind was to check this on different browsers. I have been using Firefox all this time, and it were I was getting the issue. **I tested on Chrome, Opera and Internet Explorer which output the printing perfectly fine.**

Comment: This is not an HTML/CSS issue, since the PDF is already created when you print it, and as you can see the PDF looks perfect in the PDF viewer. This means that this isn't an iText issue either: if you download the PDF and open it in Adobe Reader, it will look perfect too. So what's the problem? That's simple: every PDF viewer has print properties, and it appears that the printer properties used by the PDF viewer you are using are somewhat off.

Comment: I have tried Microsoft XPS writer, Bullzip Printer, CutePDF, DoPdf and actual printer all the while making sure the printing properties are set to A4. No luck.

Comment: I have added a download link of the file(s) at bottom of question.

Comment: I can confirm the printing behavior also happens on commercial grade printing equipment. I just ran the first 5 page of your PDF. Page 1 looks alright. Pages 4 and on, are not. The pages are thrown in the bottom left corner of the sheet.

Comment: thats an odd issue now I have to say. On downloading and saving the PDF then printing, I dont get any output issues myself. Its when I click the print action directly from the pdf viewer on the browser that this issue occurs (and it seems to be happening on Firefox only after further testing - see update on question). I will cross check your issue again just to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the 4 page example in the `.7z` file. I opened the document in Adobe Reader, and all 4 pages printed correctly. (I think that @blaze_125 tested the wrong PDF since there aren't more than 4 pages in the PDF that needed testing.)

Comment: Since Firefox uses pdf.js, there is a high chance that this is a pdf.js problem (pdf.js is the PDF viewer used by Firefox). I once had the same problem where I changed the print properties of Firefox to print a specific web page that would otherwise not fit a printed page. I forgot all about it, but when I wanted to print another page several weeks later, those specific printer properties were still in place, and the page didn't print the way I expected it. Maybe you are experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, I tested the `StackOverflow - The develo...` file as my firewall does not let me into Dropbox.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, you are correct. According to the file properties, the `StackOverflow` pdf came straight out of Indesign. I am stumped by the printing results.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, following up on Bruno's comments, I went back to print settings. I tried various combinations of settings and I see 1 constant. I get improper results every time `choose paper source by PDF size` is checked.

Comment: Are your PDFs A4 while your paper is Letter or vice versa?